# Passing Data of WebView to Another Activity

Tags: android, html, webview

I've designed a training program and Html texts and image put into training.
I want to address my html file by an activity to sent another activity.

This is MainActivity

```
        /*
     * ListView item click listener. So we'll have the do stuff on click of
     * our ListItem
     */
    listViewArticles.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
             Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(TrickPage.this,a_Dotted_Lines.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity0);
            break;
            case 1:
             Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(TrickPage.this,TutorialsPage.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity1);
            break;
            case 2:
             Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(TrickPage.this,TutorialsPage.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity2);
            break;
            case 3:
             Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(TrickPage.this,TutorialsPage.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity3);
            break;
            default:
              // Nothing do!
          }
```

and this SecondActivity (show WebView)

```
public class a_Dotted_Lines extends Activity {
private WebView webView;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.a_dotted_lines);

// Button HOME
ImageButton ImageButton_home  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_home);
ImageButton_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(a_Dotted_Lines.this, Main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
   }
});
//Button Previous
ImageButton ImageButton_previus  = (ImageButton)
findViewById(R.id.ImageButton_previus);
ImageButton_previus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    //Closing SecondScreen Activity
            finish();
   }
});

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/article.htm");

}
}
```

I want Send "file:///android_asset/html/article.htm" or other addres from MainActivity
Is it possible?
Sorry My English is not good

Comment: do you want to open another activity without any user input??

Answer (score 0):

yes it is. You can pass it through the intent you are using to start the Activity. For instance

```
 Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(TrickPage.this,TutorialsPage.class);    
 newActivity3.putExtra("url", "ur_for__case_3");
 startActivity(newActivity3);
```

and you can retrieve it the second activity throug

```
 getIntent.getExtras().getString("url");
```

the first parameter is a key, you can use to store/retrieve values in/from the intent. It has to be unique for that intent

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want to pass some data (in this case a String) from one activity to another? If so, yes you can, with the intent. In the first activity you can do

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
i.putExtra("MY_UNIQUE_ID", "file:///android_asset/html/article.htm");
startActivity(i);
```

And in the second activity you can do (in the onCreate method):

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.getStringExtra("MY_UNIQUE_ID");
```

Mind you, the convention for ID's is that you use a public static final variable and always use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create one global variable.

```
String address;
```

When user select particular webview iten then assign path to address

```
address="file:///android_asset/html/article.htm";
 Intent i= new Intent(TrickPage.this,TutorialsPage.class);    
 i.putExtra("path", address);
 startActivity(i);
```

and you can retrieve it the second activity using:

```
String getaddress;

Intent intent = getIntent();
getaddress= intent.getStringExtra("path");
```

Comment: Thank you So Much . my problem is fix. Intent intent = getIntent();
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(getaddress= intent.getStringExtra("path"));